# why are there heterogenous prices fixed for every unit of output

Tags: producer-theory

everyone says that it is because a monopoly decides the market's output, prices fixed per unit of the same keep decreasing.
question: if the firm has the ability to influence market prices, why would he bother changing the price? and even if he does, why doesnt the person produce according to the prevailing price. why does he increase production and decrease price?